# Can I show a different error message for different validation technical profiles in Azure AD B2C custom policies?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a technical profile that has two validation technical profiles:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="TechnicalProfile1">
  ...
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Validation1" ContinueOnSuccess="true" ContinueOnError="false" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Validation2" ContinueOnSuccess="true" ContinueOnError="false" />
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

They both perform an *AssertStringClaimsAreEqual* claim transformation and stop the policy's execution to show a user error message in case the claims are not equal:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Validation1">
  ...
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">Message #1</Item>
  </Metadata>
  ...
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="Assert1" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>

<TechnicalProfile Id="Validation2">
  ...
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">Message #2</Item>
  </Metadata>
  ...
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="Assert2" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

My problem is that even though every validation technical profile has it's own user message metadata item, they are not displayed when the validation fails.

Instead, the only way I could get a message to show is to add the message metadata item in the parent technical profile but then I can only show a generic error message without providing the user with information on what actually failed.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#calling-the-assertstringclaimsareequal-claims-transformation) this behavior is correct but I'm wondering if there's an option to show different messages depending on which validation failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way that you can use 'UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual' to show multiple messages. However, You can create a workaround by changing one of your assertion claim transformations to [string compare claim transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#compareclaims).

It does the same thing as string assertion but instead of throwing an error, it would return a boolean value result.

Then You can assert the boolean value using [AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue). The metadata item for boolean assertion will be

> UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual

I hope it helps!

Comment: I guess that could work as long as I won't have more validations later on :)
Thanks!